# What is the shift command doing in this example perl code for FSA::Rules?

Tags: perl

I am not very skilled in Perl, and I am trying to use FSA::Rules. What is the shift doing in this code?

```
my $fsa = FSA::Rules->new(
 ping => {
     do => sub {
         print "ping!\n";
         my $state = shift;
         $state->result('pong');
         $state->machine->{count}++;
     },
     rules => [
         game_over => sub { shift->machine->{count} >= 20 },
         pong      => sub { shift->result eq 'pong' },
     ],
 },

 pong => {
     do => sub { print "pong!\n" },
     rules => [ ping => 1, ], # always goes back to ping
 },
 game_over => { do => sub { print "Game Over\n" } }
);

$fsa->start;
$fsa->switch until $fsa->at('game_over');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default shift removes and returns the first element of the @_ array. Since that is the parameter array that is passed to subroutines, its getting the first subroutine argument. For example

```
sub { print shift; }
```

is an anonymous subroutine that just consumes and prints its first argument.

Comment: also, `shift` shifts `@ARGV` by default when outside of a subroutine.

Answer (score 3):

The `shift` command is accessing the next argument to each subroutine.

The arguments to `FSA::Rules->new` is a hash with three keys: `ping`, `pong`, and `game_over`. Let's take `ping`: it maps to another hash containing two keys: `do` and `rules`. The `do` key maps to a subroutine:

```
sub {
    print "ping!\n";
    my $state = shift;
    $state->result('pong');
    $state->machine->{count}++;
}
```

This method expects to be called with an `FSA::State` object as the argument. The other subroutines follow similar ideas. Consult the [FSA::Rules docs](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/FSA-Rules-0.29/lib/FSA/Rules.pm) for how to use all this.

Answer (score 2):

Shift removes and returns the first element of an array. When the array is not specified, @_ is assumed. @_ in that context is the list of arguments passed to the subroutine.